# how can I set google cloud storage ACL to give READ permission only to GAE apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

The bucket is project-private. So far I managed to update the ACL of the bucket through gsutil CLI. The issue is that only the owner (the app that writes/uploads the files) has access. The other apps specified in the bucket ACL get a permission error when I try to read or list the bucket content. Am I missing something ?

```
  <Entry>
        <Scope type="UserByEmail">
            <EmailAddress>
                application-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
            </EmailAddress>
        </Scope>
        <Permission>
            READ
        </Permission>
    </Entry>
 <Entry>
        <Scope type="UserByEmail">
            <EmailAddress>
                anotherapp-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
            </EmailAddress>
        </Scope>
        <Permission>
            READ
        </Permission>
    </Entry>
```

Comment: What you're doing should be correct - how are you trying to read files from the bucket? Can you try using a blobreader? (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your app's service account to your project team, as illustrated in this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/prediction_service_accounts. That tutorial focuses on using app engine with the Google Prediction API, however, the concept of enabling access to your app's service account should apply equally well when providing access to Google Cloud Storage resources to App Engine apps.

Comment: that's not possible as accounts outside of the google apps domain cannot be added to the project team. appspot.gserviceaccount.com is not our domain name so we cannot add it.

Comment: The error is @appspot.gserviceaccount.com may not be added to project "API Project". Only members from domain ourdomain.com may be added.